# Java - Initialize member with values from other members

Tags: java

I have a REST Webservice, I get my data from a JSON request:

```
@POST
@Path("load")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequestMapping(value="load", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public @ResponseBody
Respuesta loadData(@RequestBody Persons person) {
    //code
    em.persist(person);
}
```

This is my Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myparenttable", schema = "myschema", catalog = "mydb")
public class Parent {
    private Integer id_parent;
    private String name;
    private String last_name;
    private String username;

    //getters and setters
    
    public Parent(){}
    
}
```

I want to generate the username member with parts of the name and last_name members; for simplicity, lets say I need the `username` be = `name + last_name`; the `username` member is not specified in the json request, is there a way to load a member with values of other members in the object initialization? in this case, automatic initialization with `@RequestMapping` and `@RequestBody`

Comment: Is this Spring?

Comment: Normally you don't use the same class for persistence and REST API. You should create a DTO class that contains the request data then map to the persistence class in your controller. This way you can manipulate the data before persisting it. There's a good example here https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application